# Constrained Clustering Implementation R or Python?

Tags: r, clustering, python, unsupervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

Can anyone point me to an implementation in R or Python of a constrained clustering algorithm? In case this is overly broad, I am hoping to exploit known must-link/cannot-link pairs to improve the clusters (topics) generated by more common clustering algorithms, be they single (e.g. K-means) or multi-membership models (e.g. lda).

Happy to update the question if this is unclear. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a python [implementation](https://github.com/Behrouz-Babaki/copkmeans) of COP-Kmeans. There, you can also find links to other implementations of constrained clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The R package `conclust` provides this functionality.  See 
[CRAN - conclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conclust/conclust.pdf)